# How to get curly braces autocompletion in Visual Studio 2012. C #

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2012

In moste IDEs you can set so if you type for example>

```
if(isTrue) { //and when you hit enter here you get the } automatically
```

But I have not found where you get this behavior in VS Options. Is there an addon for this?

Comment: Is it not just easier to do **if** followed by **[Tab]** which creates the whole block for you?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm talking about code snippets. Also, pressing **[Enter]** after typing the condition puts the cursor inside the if statement.

Comment: Yes you are right in that case. But if you want to write a constructor or something else public MyConstructor() {//...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question on StackOverflow: [Curly braces autocomplete in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12177963/183180)

Basically either of the following free add-ins should do the trick:

- [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) (for Visual Studio Professional 2012)
- [Brace Completer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d)

Additionally you may find that code snippets can help in certain situations, e.g. typing `if` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert a boilerplate *if* statement and allow you to quickly enter the condition before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to place the cursor inside. Similarly typing `ctr` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will do the same for the class constructor. There is not one for methods included by default but it is possible to create custom snippets.

Comment: And opens up with Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector

Comment: @Chris_45: Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which adds this behavior. I believe Visual Studio is relying on the user to enter the } to trigger formatting:

[image: Options]